# Flutter UI does not update instantly even with setState(){}

Tags: flutter, setstate

I have a bottomsheet that has a bunch of list tiles one of them is "add to favorite" the main idea is when the user tap that list tile its icon and text change from `icon: heart_outline & text: add to favorite` to `icon: heart_filled & text: remove from favorite` the change is controlled by a bool `isFavorite` even when I am using setState and a stateful widget the UI doesn't change until I close the bottomsheet and reopen it again

this is the code I come up:

```
class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {
    bool isFavorite = false;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    
   @override
   void initState() {
       databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.databaseHelper;
       super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Word>>(
              future: databaseHelper.getAllWords(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Word>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          reverse: false,
                          controller: _scrollController,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                      int objId = snapshot.data[index].wordId;
                                      String germanW = snapshot.data[index].ger;
                                      String englishW = snapshot.data[index].eng;
                                      String favState = snapshot.data[index].isFav;
                                      Word currenWord = new Word(wordId: objId,eng: englishW, ger: germanW, isFav: favState);
                                      setState(() {
                                          currenWord.isFav == 'true'
                                          ? isFavorite = true
                                          : isFavorite = false;
                                          //here I open the bottomsheet
                                          trriggerBottomsheet(context, currenWord);
                                     });
                                  },
                                  child: AnimationConfiguration.staggeredList(
                                      position: index,
                                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                                      child: SlideAnimation(
                                          verticalOffset: 50.0,
                                          child: FadeInAnimation(
                                              child: listChild(snapshot.data[index].eng, snapshot.data[index].ger),
                                          ),
                                      )),
                                  );
                              },
                          );
                      }
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                   },
              ),
         );
     }

//this is the bottomsheet itself
void trriggerBottomsheet(context, Word wrd) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext buildCtx) {
            return Container(
            child: Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                // ... (irrelevant code)
            
                new ListTile(
                    leading: isFavorite == true
                      ? Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red[300],)
                      : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                    title: isFavorite == true
                      ? Text('remove from favorites')
                      : Text('add to favorites'),
                   onTap: () {
                      isFavorite == true
                      ? databaseHelper.removeFromFavorite(wrd.wordId)
                      : databaseHelper.addToFavorite(wrd.wordId);
                      setState(() {
                          isFavorite = !isFavorite;
                      });
                  },
               ),             
             ],
          ),
       );
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to keep the trigger function inside of setState. Also as far as I know setState in flutter is synchronous so this problem shouldn't arise. Let me know if moving the trigger out of setState doesn't help.

Comment: @ArshShaikh nothing happened, everything stayed as it is, and like you mentioned this shouldn't be happening but it it somehow! I can't see the change unless I close it down and reopen it !!

Comment: Just after setState try printing the value of isFavourite. Check if the state isn't changing or the widget isn't re-rendering.

Comment: @ArshShaikh it seems to be the widget isn't re-rendering, I just put the bool to test as you said and it changes fine

Comment: Also I think you'll have to change your entire implementation. You see you are rendering a List of objects and each one has it's own isFav attribute. What you are doing is maintaining a single state variable for the entire list which in itself is wrong. Every list element must have it's own state for this to work properly.

Comment: @ArshShaikh can you suggest a fix? I am not sure I'm quite following!

Comment: Make the list element to be it's own stateful widget with it's own isFavourite. That should work fine.

Comment: @ArshShaikh I started to get the hang of it but still a bit confused and frankly the idea is blurry to me, a further explanation and perhaps an example would be really nice of you!

Comment: I don't know if it'll be of much help but I'll post an answer explaining as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is there is only one state variable for the entire list.

Rather you should have a widget for the list item that has it's own state.

For example:

```
class OrderListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final OrderItem orderItem;

  const OrderListItem(this.orderItem);

  @override
  _OrderListItemState createState() => _OrderListItemState();
}

class _OrderListItemState extends State<OrderListItem> {
  var _showMore = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text('\$${widget.orderItem.amount}'),
            subtitle: Text(DateFormat().format(widget.orderItem.orderDate)),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(_showMore ? Icons.expand_less : Icons.expand_more),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _showMore = !_showMore;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          if (_showMore) Divider(),
          if (_showMore)
            Container(
              height: min(widget.orderItem.products.length * 20.0 + 10, 120),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 5,
                horizontal: 15,
              ),
              
            // irrelevant code
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here the _showMore is a state variable used for expanding a ListTile (not relevant just for context)

This is a OderListItem widget so now when I write a ListView.builder

```
ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
         OrderListItem(ordersData.orders[index]),
              itemCount: ordersData.orders.length,
           ),
```

Every element is a Stateful widget.

So when I press the showMore button on any OrderItem, it'll change only it's own state and won't affect any other items.

Implement your code in this way, it should work.

Comment: excuse the late reply, I tried what you did and followed the same logic but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Oh okay. But I don't see any other issue though. Sorry I can't be of more help